# При вызове ArrayList через объект класса: size = 0

Tags: java, arraylist

Всем привет! Не могу получить доступ к элементам `ArrayList` в другом классе, через объект класса, в котором он инициализируется. 
Я только учусь программировать, и не понимаю в чем дело. 
В коде пометил комментариями все операции с `ArrayList`.

В классе `Object` через экземпляр класса `m = new Main()` в консоли `m.Object_List.size()` выводит 0

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Pane canvas = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(canvas);

    public ArrayList<Object> Object_List = new ArrayList<>(); // Инициализация ArrayList с public 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("FXGravity");
        stage.setFullScreen(true);


        create_object(5); // Метод для заполнения Object_List
        for(Object  object : Object_List) {
            canvas.getChildren().add(object);
        }

        AnimationTimer atimer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long arg0) {
                System.out.println("size: " + Object_List.size()); // size: 5
                Object_List.get(0).gravity(); // Вызываем метод класса Object через экземпляр класса
            }
        };
        atimer.start();
    }

    public void create_object(int size) { // Заполняем Object_List
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            double x =(int)(Math.random()*1600+1);
            double y = (int)(Math.random()*900+5);
            int radius = 5;
            int mass =(int)(Math.random()*100+100);
            Object_List.add(new Object(x,y,radius,mass));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

```
public class Object extends Pane {
    final double G = 0.00006674;
    float slow = 0.1f;
    double VelX;
    double VelY;
    int mass;

    Circle circle = new Circle();
    Point2D position = new Point2D(150,150);
    Main m = new Main(); // Создаем экзмпляр класса, в котором инициализирован Object_List

    public Object (double x, double y, int radius, int mass) {
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        circle.setCenterX(x - radius/2);
        circle.setCenterY(y - radius/2);
        circle.setFill(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        this.mass=mass;

        position = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX() - radius/2, circle.getCenterY() - radius/2);

        getChildren().add(circle);
    }

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setVelX(double VelX) {
        this.VelX = VelX;
    }

    public void setVelY(double VelY) {
        this.VelY = VelY;
    }


    public double getVelX() {
        return VelX;
    }

    public double getVelY() {
        return VelY;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------

    public void move() {
        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + getVelY());
        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + getVelY());
    }

    public void gravity() {
        System.out.println("gravity() obj_lst size: " + m.Object_List.size()); // size: 0  ??? 
        for(int i = 0; i < m.Object_List.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m.Object_List.size(); j++) {

                if (j == i) {
                    continue;
                }

                m.Object_List.get(i).setVelX(

                        slow*G*(m.Object_List.get(i).mass * m.Object_List.get(j).mass) / 
                        m.Object_List.get(i).position.getX()*m.Object_List.get(j).position.getX() );

                m.Object_List.get(i).setVelY(

                        slow*G*(m.Object_List.get(i).mass * m.Object_List.get(j).mass) / 
                        m.Object_List.get(i).position.getY()*m.Object_List.get(j).position.getY() );

//              object_1 ->> G*(m1*m2/r*r) <<- object_2     
            }   
        }
        move();
    }
}
```

Comment: А в какой момент вызывается `@Override start()`?

Comment: в public static void main: launch(); Это библиотека JavaFX

Сделал костыль, создал в классе Object еще один ArrayList и перекинул туда элементы из ArrayList в классе Main. Доступ к этим элементам получил, но графика не отрисовалась. А это уже другая проблема :)

Comment: Метод `handle()` в `AnimationTimer` (это все в `start()` ), там происходит вызов метода `gravity()` из класса `Object`. В методе `gravity()` я и пытаюсь обратится к массиву, а он пустой... А чем сбивает название Object?   Проблема актуальна, использование костыля мне совсем не нравится.

Comment: Надо как-то распутать перекрестные ссылки на ваши объекты. У вас лист ваших объектов лежит в `Main`. Тут же в этом же классе вы создаете (`new`) инициализируете (`create_object()`) ваш лист... Дальше следите за руками... При инициализации листа вы создаете ваш `Object`, и в каждом созданном экземпляре есть переменная `Main m`, которая создает НОВЫЙ экземпляр класса `Main`. Но метод `launch()` вы запустили всего один раз из самого первого экземпляра `Main`, соответственно, `create_object()` выполнился только 1 раз и заполнил он лист, который был в этом экзеспляре. Остальные экземпляры - пустые!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы как-то поосторожнее относитесь к инкапсуляции, правилам именования переменных и прочим базовым вещам.

Разбивайте код на классы и методы осмысленно, а не случайным образом.

Игнорирование фундаментальных простейших правил ведут к наиболее тяжелым последствиям. Именно это случилось у вас. Имея тривиальнейшую задачу, вы написали столь запутанный код, что не смогли отладить. Я немного изменил его и превратил в рабочий, но это за гранью добра и зла, простите.

По этому коду советов никаких давать не буду, просто предоставлю рабочий вариант, но в целом совет один — зайдите ко мне в профиль и почитайте мои ответы. Я стараюсь давать расширенные ответы, комментируя свои действия. Привожу наиболее простые для понимания примеры насколько это возможно в ООП. Зачастую ссылаюсь на паттерны и т.д. Попробуйте разобраться с примерами, которые я привожу. Зачастую это решение учебных задач, которые будут намного более полезны, чем этот код.

Если будут вопросы — пишите.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final static double G = 0.00006674;
    private final static double SLOW = 0.1;

    private final List<Object> objectList;

    public Main() {
        this.objectList = createObject(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas);
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("FXGravity");
        stage.setFullScreen(true);

        for (Object object : objectList) canvas.getChildren().add(object);

        AnimationTimer atimer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long arg0) {
                gravity();
            }
        };
        atimer.start();
    }

    private List<Object> createObject(int size) {
        int radius = 5;
        final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            double x =(int)(Math.random()*1600+1);
            double y = (int)(Math.random()*900+5);
            int mass =(int)(Math.random()*100+100);
            list.add(new Object(x,y,radius,mass));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private void gravity() {

        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < objectList.size(); j++) {
                if (j == i) continue;
                objectList.get(i).setVelX(SLOW * G * objectList.get(i).getMass() * objectList.get(j).getMass()
                        / objectList.get(i).getPosition().getX() * objectList.get(j).getPosition().getX());
                objectList.get(i).setVelY(SLOW * G * objectList.get(i).getMass() * objectList.get(j).getMass()
                        / objectList.get(i).getPosition().getY() * objectList.get(j).getPosition().getY());                
            }
        }

        for (Object obj : objectList) obj.move();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}


import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Object extends Pane {

    private final int mass;    
    private double VelX, VelY;
    private final Circle circle;
    private Point2D position;

    public Object(double x, double y, int radius, int mass) {
        this.circle = new Circle();
        this.position = new Point2D(150, 150);
        this.mass = mass;        
        this.circle.setRadius(radius);
        this.circle.setCenterX(x - radius / 2);
        this.circle.setCenterY(y - radius / 2);
        this.circle.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));        

        this.position = new Point2D(circle.getCenterX() - radius / 2, circle.getCenterY() - radius / 2);

        getChildren().add(circle);
    }

    public Point2D getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public int getMass() {
        return mass;
    }

    public void setVelX(double VelX) {
        this.VelX = VelX;
    }

    public void setVelY(double VelY) {
        this.VelY = VelY;
    }

    public double getVelX() {
        return VelX;
    }

    public double getVelY() {
        return VelY;
    }

    public void move() {
        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + getVelY());
        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + getVelY());
    }

}
```

*От меня вам большое спасибо! Это самое изящное решение моей проблемы, вопросов по коду нет - всё работает так как и должно работать!*
Если вы измените формулу в методе `gravity()` на

```
double DX = objectList.get(j).circle.getCenterX() - objectList.get(i).circle.getCenterX();
                double DY = objectList.get(j).circle.getCenterY() - objectList.get(i).circle.getCenterY();;
                double R = Math.sqrt(DX*DX) + (DY*DY);

                double FORCE = G * objectList.get(i).getMass() * objectList.get(j).getMass() / R;

                double ACCELI = FORCE / objectList.get(i).getMass();
                double ACCELJ = FORCE / objectList.get(j).getMass();

                DX /= R;
                DY /= R;

                objectList.get(i).setVelX(objectList.get(i).getVelX() + ACCELI * DX);
                objectList.get(i).setVelY(objectList.get(i).getVelY() + ACCELJ * DY);

                objectList.get(j).setVelX(objectList.get(j).getVelX() - ACCELI * DX);
                objectList.get(j).setVelY(objectList.get(j).getVelY() - ACCELJ * DY);
```

то сможете посмотреть на моделирование Ньютоновской гравитации :) Добавьте 50+ объектов, вместо 5.

И в методе `move()` измените одну букву, там в первой строчке к X прибавляется Y, а должен X к X.

Comment: `double R = Math.sqrt((DX*DX) + (DY*DY));` Иначе объекты будут двигаться только по оси X. Я не до конца разобрался как работает этот сервис, поэтому вместо комментария сюда, изменил ваш ответ.

Comment: @Evoque спасибо, конечно, но изящным это назвать сложно)) это просто рабочий код, что довольно несложно на такой простой задаче. если увеличить сложность бизнесс-логики хотя бы в 100 раз (а для типичных приложений, реализуемых на джаве, это далеко не предел), то подобные решения будет невозможно использовать. мой совет прежний - смотрите примеры кода , которые я выкладываю, задавайте вопросы. обычно те примеры, которые я привожу, значительно лучше, чем код в данном решении. удачи